# Template by post id?

Tags: wordpress

I have done some php modifications to content.php in my theme to add some custom fields and images in posts.

I have 440 old posts that i don't want to apply this changes on.

What would be the easiest way to apply the new content.php on all posts from id 441?

**code:**

```
<?php
if(is_post(441)){

Show new code here

} else {

Show old code here

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to attempt to get the value of a custom field, then check to see if it worked.

In other words, I think something like this would work better:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($id, 'custom_field_slug', true); 

if($custom_field) {
   //code to execute if custom field has value
}
```

Comment: Thx but i did find another solutions since there were som other elements that i needed to hide.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
global $post;
if ( $post->ID >= 441 ){
 // do something
}
```